# javascript add button with two input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write this in javascript without using jquery. It basically has two input field: author and quote, and on click should be added to the page.

I'm also trying to save it on the page in case I leave the page. The added quote disappears when i execute the method:

```js
function radd() {
    if((document.getElementById("q").value!="") && (document.getElementById("a").value!="")) {
        $("#mid-wraper" ).append("<p class='left-bullet'>"+document.getElementById("q").value+"-<span class='yellow-heading'>"+ document.getElementById("a").value+"</span></p>");
        document.getElementById("q").value="";
        document.getElementById("a").value="";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but" onClick="radd()">Add</button>
    <label for="q">Add ur Quote!</label><input id="q" name="q" />
    <label for="a">The author name</label><input id="a" name="a" />
```

Comment: Also, please propose this question as HTML/JS snippet, natively embedded here in stackoverflow

Comment: @sim123 I have edited your question to allow other programmers to better understand what you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function radd()
{
  if((document.getElementById("q").value!="")&&   (document.getElementById("a").value!=""))
    document.getElementById("mid-wraper").innerHTML += "<p class='left-bullet'>"+document.getElementById("q").value+"-<span class='yellow-heading'>"+ document.getElementById("a").value+"</span></p>";
    document.getElementById("q").value="";
    document.getElementById("a").value="";
}
```

Comment: Small tip: have a look at the += operator

Comment: where you want to save??

Comment: is there any way to save the input from the user .even i exit the page

Comment: I dont know through javascript but you can save data in mysql table and every time you can fetch it from the table

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(){
 //create a new elem
 var el=document.createElement("p");
 //you can assign id, class , etc
 el.id="yourcustomid";
 el.textContent="yourcontent";
 //then add to the wrapper
 var wrapper=document.getElementById("mid-wrapper");
 wrapper.appendChild(el);
 }
```

This code shows you how to create a new paragraph and add it to your wrapper js...

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this; far more easier in my opinion. Simply create both inputs, but set their attributes to hidden. And using javascript, delete the "hidden" attribute.

```
<button id="but" onClick="radd()">Add</button>
<input id="q" hidden="hidden" >Add ur Quote!</input>
<input id="a" hidden="hidden">The author name</input>
```

The JS part:

```
function radd(){
  document.getElementById("q").removeAttribute("hidden");
  document.getElementById("a").removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```